# SQL modify order of columns and add new columns from query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I would like to know how to do the following operation, if possible:

Sample of the original table:

```
Type      Status    I1    I2    I3    I4    I5
 A          ON      3     4     2     10    2
 A         OFF      1     1     0     null  null
 B          ON      5     6     2     10    2
 B         OFF      2     1     2     null  null
 C          ON      8     7     5     10    2
 C         OFF      1     1     1     null  null
 A          ON      4     4     4     10    2
 A         OFF      2     2     1     null  null
 B          ON      5     4     5     10    2
 B         OFF      1     1     1     null  null
```

So, basically what I would like is to merge the `I` values from `ON` and `OFF` status, in the following way:

Taking the table above, the values `I1`,`I2`, `I3` from `OFF status` will become `I6`, `I7`,`I8` output would be

```
Type      I1    I2    I3    I4    I5    I6    I7   I8
 A        3     4     2     10    2     1     1    0
 B        5     6     2     10    2     2     1    2
 C        8     7     5     10    2     1     1    1
 A        4     4     4     10    2     2     2    1
 B        5     4     5     10    2     1     1    1
```

To be clear, what It would do is just to take the values `I1`, `I2` and `I3` from the `OFF status` of each `type` and put them together with the results from the `ON status` as `I6`, `I7`, `I8`

Comment: Do you have an `id` column?

Comment: sorry yes, I always forget to post the ID columns, it is present as a primary key

Comment: What do you want to do with the second set of Type A and Type B? Should they be a separate row?
Could you give us just one more line of the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `id` column is auto-incremented *and* it has no gaps, then you might be in luck

```
select o1.*, o2.i1 as i6, o2.i2 as i7, o2.i3 as i8
from original o1 join
     original o2
     on o2.id = o1.id + 1 and
        o2.type = o1.type and
        o1.status = 'ON' and o2.status = 'OFF';
```

Otherwise, this query is much harder than it seems.  You need to group the similar `id`s.  One method is to identify them by the number of similar rows with the same type and `ON`.  You can get this with a correlated subquery:

```
with o as (
      select o.*,
             (select count(*)
              from original o2
              where o2.type = o.type and o2.status = 'ON' and o2.id <= o.id
             ) as grp
      from original o
     )
select o.type,
       max(case when type = 'ON' then i1 end) as i1,
       max(case when type = 'ON' then i2 end) as i2,
       max(case when type = 'ON' then i3 end) as i3,
       max(case when type = 'ON' then i4 end) as i4,
       max(case when type = 'ON' then i5 end) as i5,
       max(case when type = 'OFF' then i1 end) as i6,
       max(case when type = 'OFF' then i2 end) as i7,
       max(case when type = 'OFF' then i3 end) as i8
from o
group by grp, type ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Type, SUM(I1) AS I1, SUM(I2) AS I2, SUM(I3) AS I3, SUM(I4) AS I4, SUM(I5) AS I5, SUM(I6) AS I6, SUM(I7) AS I7, SUM(I8) AS I8
FROM (
    SELECT Type, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, 0 As I6, 0 As I7, 0 As I8
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Status = 'ON'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Type, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, I1 As I6, I2 As I7, I3 As I8
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Status = 'OFF') DT
GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: buff...thanks shA, I am not very good yet with SQL, need some time to read and understand this big thing

Comment: maybe you need to modify your answer a bit according to the last edit of my question...I thinnk I didint explain correctly the first time, I have updated the question with more rows in the desired output

Comment: @newPyUser Can you explain it how do you specify a row with `OFF` status to a row with `ON` status where there are more than one Type for each of them?